# WPF Data binding to observableCollection

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Can someone give me a little help with this one please
I'm trying to reorganise an app to MVVM and make better use of data binding, but am struggling with a little issue.

I have a viewmodel class

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<DiagramElement> Elements { get; set; }


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        AppMachineList = new ListOfMachines();
        Elements = new ObservableCollection<DiagramElement>();
    } 
}
```

in which I create an observablecollection of the DiagramElement class.

```
public class DiagramElement : Button
{
    private Item linkedItem;

    public Item LinkedItem
    {
        get { return this.linkedItem; }
        set
        {
            this.linkedItem = value;
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.Template = (ControlTemplate)FindResource("ItemTemplate");

        }
    }
```

The DiagramElement class just extends the button class and adds its own controlTemplate.

Back in my MainWindow.xaml.cs class, I instantiate the viewmodel and from that, populate a stackpanel in MainWindow.xaml from the ObservableCollection.

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        vm.LoadMachines();

        foreach(DiagramElement d in vm.Elements)
        {
            ItemList.Children.Add(d);
        }

    }
}

<StackPanel x:Name="ItemList" Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
```

What I want to do is, do away with the foreach loop and the calls to ItemList.Children.Add(). And replace this with a binding to Elements in the viewmodel like below.

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        MainWindowViewModel vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        vm.LoadMachines();

        this.DataContext = vm;

    }
}

<StackPanel x:Name="ItemList" DataContext="{Binding Path=Elements}"</Stackpanel>
```

I can't get the elements to be added to the Stackpanel, the binding doesn't work. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You have misunderstood the MVVM concept. UI stuff should not be there in ViewModel. It is meant to hold only data and not UI control (button in your case).

Comment: Yes, the buttons were originally created in MainWindow. I was trying to work something out and moved them to the view model. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, having a ViewModel with a collection of UI elements (in your case, buttons) violates the principles of MVVM -- the UI and model should not be co-mingled like this.

But the immediate problem is you cannot use a StackPanel -- it is a control container but does not support binding to lists of items.  You need to use some kind of repeater like an `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <!-- your DiagramElement should go here, something like
      <DiagramElement LinkedItem={Binding Path=SomePropertyOnYourRevisedElement} />
      -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But there's more work to be done.  `DiagramElement` needs to have `LinkedItem` converted into a `DependencyProperty` (lots of examples of this online) and `Elements` needs to be a list of some sort of model object that just stores the properties needed for the DiagramElement (with no UI stuff).

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the reply, have done something similar to what you advise in a previous project, think I may be over complicating things. Yes am intending to remove the UI Collection from the view model.